# How to send Notification to the Particular User in Socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I have created the Simple blog using MEAN Stack,  each post  is having the comment section, i want to send the notification to the particular user(post Admin)  When the comment has been made on the post. can anybdy give the Suggestion how to do this using socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick ways you could do this:

**Option 1:**
Create a hash for every user and only emit on the user hash.

```
socket.emit('##somehash##', { post_msg: 'You have a new post' });
```

**Option 2:**
Create an "admin" channel (not secure) and then broadcast the message over the admin channel.
http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: ##somehash## how to generate this hash?